# How to do page refresh with token management with middleware in NextJS?

Tags: next.js, cookies, next.js13, next-auth, next.js14

I'm using Nextjs 14.

I have successfully implemented logic for handling both refresh and access tokens in my application. This was achieved through the use of middleware for setting cookies, and I'm utilizing NextAuth for authentication. I've been trying to solve this for a whole week and looked for every kind of possible solution. I would appreciate your support!

This is my `middleware.ts` :

```js
export default withAuth(
  async function middleware(req) {
    const url = req.nextUrl.clone();

    // Redirect root path to /courses
    if (req.nextUrl.pathname === "/") {
      url.pathname = "/courses";
      return NextResponse.redirect(url);
    }

    const response = NextResponse.next();
    const refreshToken = req.cookies.get("refresh_token")?.value;
    const accessToken = req.cookies.get("access_token")?.value;

    console.log("refreshTokenNew", refreshToken);

    // Handling refresh token
    if (!accessToken && refreshToken) {
      try {
        const serverResponse = await fetch(`${Backend_URL}/user/refresh-token`, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Cookie: `refresh_token=${refreshToken}`
          },
          credentials: "include",
        });

        if (serverResponse.ok) {
          const setCookieHeader = serverResponse.headers.get("set-cookie");
          setCookiesFromHeader(response, setCookieHeader);
          console.log("set cookie header", setCookieHeader);

          return response; // return NextResponse.redirect(url)
        } else {
          req.cookies.clear();
          return NextResponse.redirect(`${Frontend_URL}/login`);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Middleware error:", error);
        return NextResponse.redirect(`${Frontend_URL}/login`);
      }
    }

    return response;
  },
  {
    callbacks: {
      authorized: ({ req, token }) => {
        // Redirect unauthenticated users trying to access dashboard routes
        if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/dashboard") && !token) {
          return false;
        }

        // Prevent students from accessing teacher paths
        if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/teacher") &&
            token &&
            token.role === "STUDENT") {
          return false;
        }

        return true;
      },
    },
  }
);

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)"],
};
```

I make the fetch request inside my server component this way:

```js
export async function makeFetch(url: string, options: RequestInit = {}) {
  // Set default options, especially for credentials
  const defaultOptions: RequestInit = {
    method: "GET",
    credentials: "include", // This should be a value from 'omit', 'same-origin', or 'include'
    headers: { Cookie: cookies().toString() },
    ...options,
  };

  let response = await fetch(url, defaultOptions);

  // Retry the request if the response is 401
  if (response.status === 401) {
    response = await fetch(url, defaultOptions);
  }

  return response;
}

const EditCourse = async ({ params }: Props) => {
  const response = await makeFetch(`${Backend_URL}/courses/${params.courseId}/teacher`);

  // Check if the request was successful
  if (response.ok) {
    const course = await response.json();
    return (
      <div>
        Edit course {params.courseId}
        {JSON.stringify(course.data)}
      </div>  
    );
  } else {
    // Handle other errors
    const errorText = await response.text();
    return <div>Error: {errorText}</div>;
  }
};

export default EditCourse;
```

The problem now is that when the `access_token` expires, it shows the error message altough I can see the cookie set. I can see the course content only when I refresh the page.

I tried adding `NextResponse.redirect(new URL(req.url))` to redirect to the same page when the response is successful, but it ends up entering in a loop telling `too many requests` and asking to delete the cookies.

My logic behind redirecting is that I would expect that since the `access_token` cookie is set the first time, the if block `if (!accessToken && refreshToken)` should not be executed!

How to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In makeFetch, use headers option like this: "headers: headers()," and remove "headers: { Cookie: cookies().toString() },". Then try it again. If it fails, get your cookie like this: "const refreshToken = cookies().get("refresh_token")?.value;const accessToken = cookies().get("access_token")?.value;" in your middleware. Then try again. Please share the result with me